# Django 1.8 forms.EmailField check

Tags: django, forms

forms.py

```
email = forms.EmailField()
email2 = forms.EmailField()
```

What is the best solution to check given emails are the same ?

I'm try

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    email2 = self.cleaned_data['email2']
    if email != email2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Emails do not match")
    return email
```

or

```
def clean(self):
    if (self.cleaned_data.get('email') !=
        self.cleaned_data.get('email2')):

        raise ValidationError("Email addresses do not match.")

    return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: both are ok. but first one has more readability

Answer (score 0):

I think both solutions are good, but I prefer the second one, it is more cleaned and no innecessary variables.

Bye!